# I'm not able to save images on the blog through API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an api in ASP.NET Core to save images in the azure blob, but for some reason when I make the request it's giving error 500

[image: error 500]

```
private async Task<string> Salvar(BlobStorageModel blobStorageModel)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{_blobStorageApiUrl}/api/BlobsStorages")
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blobStorageModel), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        var response = _httpClient.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        string retorno = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(retorno);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("");
          
        }
    }
```

I configured on azure to accept https over TLS/SSL

Comment: but I didn't put C, I used C#

Comment: my apologies, I guess you had a typo and didn't realize it, because I removed the `c` tag. See [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71535159/revisions)

Comment: Thank you I hadn't noticed rs thanks

Comment: What error are you getting in your api?

Comment: @Amanb Id = 441, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error',

Comment: The real error will be in your other api `tijoforte`

Comment: you speak in the container in azure?

Comment: yeah, I am assuming that is the api which is saving blob in azure. Check the error in its logs

Comment: Please check the log in your azure webapp, or you can show us the code about `api/BlobsStorages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The 500 error is from your api-tijoforte site, not yours.**

If you have permission, you can show us the code about `api/BlobsStorages`, 500 error seems there are some code issue.

If you don't have permisson to check, you need to contact the site owner, let them help you check the logs and show the correct way to use this method.

And we suggest you use postman tool to test the api interface first, then you can write it in your code.

Comment: @thiagogcorreabotelho Pls create a new post, and provided the code about `api/BlobsStorages`. You also need to add the test result img for us. You can @ me under this thread after you create a new one.

Comment: In this thread we can't do any more, we have found the reason why the issue occured.